# Numpy change all elements on condition on multidimensional array

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I want to change elements to be [0,0,0] if the pixel at that color is blue. The code below works, but is extremely slow:

```
for row in range(w):
    for col in range(h):
        if np.array_equal(image[row][col], [255,0,0]):
            image[row][col] = (0,0,0)
        else:
            image[row][col] = (255,255,255)
```

I know np.where works for single dimensional arrays, but how can I use that function to replace stuff for a 3 dimensional object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you brought up `numpy.where`, this is how you'd do it using `nupmy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

# Make an example image
image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10, 10, 3))
image[2, 2, :] = [255, 0, 0]

# Define the color you're looking for
pattern = np.array([255, 0, 0])

# Make a mask to use with where
mask = (image == pattern).all(axis=2)
newshape = mask.shape + (1,)
mask = mask.reshape(newshape)

# Finish it off
image = np.where(mask, [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255])
```

The reshape is in there so that numpy will apply [broadcasting](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/intro_numpy.html#broadcasting), [more here also](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could do is just multiply the element you want to set to a zero array *by zero*. An example of this array property for a three dimensional array is shown below.

```
x = array([ [ [ 1,2,3 ] , [ 2 , 3 , 4 ] ] , [ [ 1, 2, 3, ] , [ 2 , 3 , 4 ] ] , [ [ 1,2,3 ] , [ 2 , 3 , 4 ] ] , [ [ 1, 2, 3, ] , [ 2 , 3 , 4 ] ] ])

print x

if 1:
    x[0] = x[0] * 0

print x
```

This will yield two printouts:

[[[1 2 3]
  [2 3 4]]

[[1 2 3]
  [2 3 4]]...

and

[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

[[1 2 3] 
 [2 3 4]]...

This method will work for both image[row], and image[row][column] in your example. Your example reworked would look like:

```
for row in range(w):
    for col in range(h):
        if np.array_equal(image[row][col], [255,0,0]):
            image[row][col] = 0
        else:
            image[row][col] = 255
```

Comment: This doesn't help, the problem is still the same, that there's still two for loops, so its extremely slow